# Dust sensor for Arduino in open and windy environment

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I intend to create a DIY dust sensor, specifically Particulate Matter up to 10 micrometer in size (PM10) using Arduino UNO for the region surrounding a building which is located next to a factory that produces wood-based products. Is there any specific sensor that should suit my need, that is to collect and measure dust particles in an open environment and possibly a windy condition?
Any implementation ideas are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A popular option is the Shinyei PPD42 sensor. There are a few well-documented blogs that describe how to connect it to an Arduino. Some of the users determined that the sensors are more accurate when a fan is placed on the unit to blow air through it, but this might not be necessary in an outdoors and windy environment.

I have two of these sensors hooked up to an Arduino, one monitoring indoors and one outdoors. I found that the indoors unit needed a fan on it to help it detect particles better (otherwise I was getting too many zeros). But the outdoors unit seems fine without the fan.

I mainly followed this blog's instructions for the code:
http://www.howmuchsnow.com/arduino/airquality/grovedust/

I think I read a few months ago that the next best sensors are in the $200 range.

I have a Dylos DC1100 dust monitor (considered very accurate) and it usually correlates with my Shinyei readings. But I'm pretty sure I introduced some "magic numbers" into my code to make the Shinyei readings match more closely with the Dylos. The entire process wasn't easy for me, and it took me weeks to get everything to behave the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how far you want to go.  If you are looking for something cheap, than a GP2Y1010AU0F will only cost you a few pounds.  Or you could step up to £30 GBP or even £1000GBP.

Since you are looking at using an Arduino and not a PC then I'm guessing the GP2Y1010AU0F would be a good idea.  I haven't tried it but this site should steer you the right way: http://arduinodev.woofex.net/2012/12/01/standalone-sharp-dust-sensor/